Decorator and Class/Instance Methods
I have a class to preload data into cache when an event happens. I want to register loader functions with a decorator and an event key, so that when the event fires, I can execute the functions.
from collections import defaultdict

class Preloader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.events = defaultdict(set)

    def register(self, event_key: str):
        print(f"Registering event: `{event_key}`")

        def decorator(func):
            print("Decorating function: ", func.__qualname__)

            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                print("Wrapper called...")
                # call func, add results to cache, return results
                return func(*args, **kwargs)

            self.events[event_key].add(wrapper)
            return wrapper

        return decorator

    def preload(self, event_key: str, *args, **kwargs):
        for func in self.events[event_key]:
            func(*args, **kwargs)


Then I decorate functions with the register method.
preloader = Preloader()

class Product:

    @staticmethod
    @preloader.register("products")
    def get_products_static():
        # there would really be a database call here
        print("Getting products from static method...")

    @classmethod
    @preloader.register("products")
    def get_products_cls(cls):
        # there would really be a database call here
        print("Getting products from class method...")

When I call preloader.preload('products'), the class method call fails with
TypeError: Product.get_products_cls() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls'

How can I modify my decorator to accept class and instance methods?

Your question doesn't define a method named get_products; are you calling get_products_static or get_products_cls? (Presumably the latter, but please fix your question to be clear.)

The decorator isn't really the problem. self.events["products"] contains a pair of functions with different signatures, but no way to know which ones need arguments.

@chepner Thanks, fixed the get_products typo. I figured Python would automatically pass the Product class into the class method as part of the args? That doesn't seem to be happening.

I'm not sure your Preloader system makes any sense applied to a class- or instance-method. What class or instance do you expect the method to be called on? It should work if you pass in those arguments (e.g. preloader.preload('products', Product)), but without them you're always going to get an error.

@ChandlerSommerville That's only when you access get_product_cls as an attribute of Product; you are storing a direct reference to the function object in the events dict.

I recommend reading through the descriptor how-to, with a special focus on how class methods and static methods are implemented and how they behave.
